# Script executing

Tags: php, python

I am executing Python script in PHP which is working fine. I am getting the output of Python script on my webpage. But the problem is that I created a variable in PHP which has the same value as the result of Python code but when I'm comparing both it is showing not equal.

**Python:**

```
if(results==[True]):
print("picture matched")
```

**Result:**
`picture matched`

**PHP:**

```
$output = shell_exec("python check.py");
var_dump($output);
$out = "picture matched";
var_dump($out);
if($output == $out) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "not";
}
```

**Result:**
`string (16) "picture matched " string (16) "picture matched " not`

I don't know why it's showing `not`, it should show `match` because both have the same type, value, and characters.

Comment: Looks like the Python script is actually returning `picture matched ` (with a trailing space)

Comment: Surely the space in your strings is not accurate. ` `

Comment: @sundance That's what I thought too, but the `var_dump($out)` is also showing with a space?

Comment: The `python` `print()` statement adds a newline on the end by default, which you probably don't notice.  Try `print("picture matched", end="")`

Comment: @UnknownProgrammer Something is wrong with your PHP deployment or you copy/pasted incorrectly. `var_dump` of `"picture matched"` is 15 characters, not 16, and no space/new line. https://3v4l.org/DPAmJ

Comment: @UnknownProgrammer mark cdarke as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

The python 3 `print()` function adds a newline on the end by default, which you probably don't notice. Try:

```
print("picture matched", end="")
```

The python 2 `print` statement equivalent: `print "picture matched",` (with a trailing comma) does not add a newline but does add a trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO using == for strings isn't always 100% accurate.  Try using strcmp:

```
$output=shell_exec("python check.py");
     var_dump($output);
     $out="picture matched";
     var_dump($out);
     if(strcmp($output,$out) != 0)
     {
       echo "match";
     }
     else
        { echo "not";
     }
```

You cua also use it to help determine the issue.  It will returns < 0 if $output is less than $out or > 0 if $output is greater than $out, and obviously 0 if they are equal.

```
$output=shell_exec("python check.py");
     var_dump($output);
     $out="picture matched";
     var_dump($out);
     if(strcmp($output,$out) != 0)
     {
       echo "match";
     }
     else
        { echo "not";
          echo strcmp($output,$out);
     }
```